# SQL Array within a cell

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sql-function

I have a cell that contains an array of characters seperated by commas i.e. "1,2,3,4,5" My question is, is it possible to remove a particular element of the array such as if I wanted to remove "1" then the cell would then become "2,3,4,5" or remove "3" and it becomes "1,2,4,5" I want to perform this task within SQL either as a function or a stored procedure, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: That is really bad database design. If you have the ability to do so, you should move away from storing multiple values in the same column ASAP.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, it'd just be some basic string REPLACE() calls: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx

However, since you have to manipulate individual bits of this data field separately from the rest of the field, it's a good candidate for getting normalized into its own child table.

Comment: I **strongly** recommend getting this column into it's own table.  For oh-so-many-reasons (ability to index _usefully_, ease of use, referential constraints...)